# ioctl(sock, SIOCETHTOOL, &ifr) why its returning -1 all the time

Tags: c++, sockets, ethernet, ioctl

/* Same piece of code  works differently for two different version of Linux & there out put as below

Linux mammo-linux 2.6.27.19-5-default #1 SMP 2009-02-28 04:40:21 +0100 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Out put :
Returning false

Linux inblrbuildserver01 3.0.13-0.27-default #1 SMP Wed Feb 15 13:33:49 UTC 2012 (d73692b) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Output:
SPEED is : 100Mbps
*/

```
#include <sys/socket.h>#
##include <sys/ioctl.h> ##
###include <netinet/in.h>###
####include <linux/sockios.h>####
#####include <linux/if.h>#####
#####include <linux/ethtool.h> #####
######include <string.h>######
#######include <stdlib.h>#######
//#include <linux/wireless.h>
########include<iostream>#######
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int sock;
    struct ifreq ifr;
    struct ethtool_cmd edata;
    int rc;

    sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP);
    if (sock < 0) {
      //  perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, "eth0", sizeof(ifr.ifr_name));
    ifr.ifr_data = &edata;

    edata.cmd = ETHTOOL_GSET;

    rc = ioctl(sock, SIOCETHTOOL, &ifr);
    if (rc < 0) {
    //    perror("ioctl");
    cout<<" Returning false " <<endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    switch (edata.speed) {
        case SPEED_10: printf(" SPEED is : 10Mbps\n"); break;
        case SPEED_100: printf("SPEED is : 100Mbps\n"); break;
        case SPEED_1000: printf("1Gbps\n"); break;
        case SPEED_2500: printf("2.5Gbps\n"); break;
        case SPEED_10000: printf("10Gbps\n"); break;
        default: printf("Speed returned is %d\n", edata.speed);
    }

    return (0);
}

/*Linux mammo-linux 2.6.27.19-5-default #1 SMP 2009-02-28 04:40:21 +0100 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Returning false

Linux inblrbuildserver01 3.0.13-0.27-default #1 SMP Wed Feb 15 13:33:49 UTC 2012 (d73692b) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

SPEED is : 100Mbps

*/
```

Can any one help for this ???

Comment: Please format your code and text. Also, read the ioctl manpage concerning errors, add according code and the results to your question.

Answer (score 1):

That's perhaps because `ETHTOOL_GSET` is not implemented in kernel 2.6.27's driver for your network adapter. You could tell with greater certainty if you hadn't commented out `perror("ioctl")`.